# Is there a way to make a toplevel GTK window smaller than the default minimum size?

Tags: gtk

I need to draw a few small undecorated windows on top of another app's window. Each of these windows contains just a short label. It works fine but the windows are too big for my purpose. It seems as if Windows doesn't allow smaller than 104 x 27 toplevel windows, I might be wrong. I haven't tested on another backends. I'd like to shrink them to just the size needed to display the label. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Trying out things, I figured that setting the type hint with `gtk_window_set_type_hint` to `GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_UTILITY` allows the window to shrink horizontally but not vertically. I'm not sure what other implications this has. But it didn't solve the problem anyway.

I'm looking for a portable solution but platform-dependand answers are welcome too. Any help appreciated.

Edit: As usual, the solution is trivial. I had completely forgotten the `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` window type.

Edit: Making the window `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` has some unfortunate side effects which make it unusable for my purpose. I eventually got `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL` to work as expected. The key was to do `gtk_window_set_resizable(window, FALSE)` after the the window has been exposed.

Comment: You should add an answer in your question, and then accept it so that other people may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gtk_window_set_resizable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-resizable), this affects *user* resizes, which apparently includes resizes requested by the window manager. Setting it to FALSE therefore makes the programmatic value stick.